# Getting error while importing Excel file using POI in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, apache-poi, soapui

I am stuck at 1 point where i wan't to fetch excel data having formula, i am able to achieve this in Eclipse and tried using same jars in soapUI but getting below error:

Getting error on below code:

[image: error_image]

ERROR:An error occurred [Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLTypeLoader], see error log for details

Using below jars in my ext folder.

[image: jar_image]

Below are the error logs Caused by:

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56) at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:63)

Comment: "see error log for details". Please do that and tell us what you found.

Comment: @AxelRichter : Below are the error logs  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:63)

Comment: Not sure it is the problem, but I see you are using XSSF for an .xls XSSF is for .xlsx and HSSF is for .xls https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/

Comment: no, xls part is commented out i am using xlxs, you can see in fileinputsteam.

Comment: My guess based on experience is that you have an incorrect version of xmlbeans. It's very difficult to say. Eclipse may have a different build path for some of the jars.

Comment: SoapUI already comes with a lot of these jars, however different versions - see $SOAPUI_HOME/lib. You putting these in the ext folder will cause classpath conflicts.